# Oracle APEX, Interactive Grid, Check in JS if column is visible

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to set values in an oracle interactive grid to every checked row.

But my loop via `setValue` sets also values in cells, that are hidden/that are not in current view.

Is it possible to check via JS, whether a column is visible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to check if a column is visible

```
var ig$ = apex.region("myGridStaticID").widget(),
    view = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");


if(view.modelColumns["MyColumnName"].hidden) {

   console.log("this column is hidden);
 }
```